# Not seeing superclasses in Eclipse new java class wizard

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to learn some Android and java programming in Eclipse. I can run sample projects and tutorials fine, but when I try to create a new java class with File->New->Class and press the Browse button to look for superclasses to use, nothing shows up in the "Matching items:" area, even when I delete the "java.lang.Object" default type. I should be seeing lots of class names there, shouldn't I?

The same lack of results happens when I try to add and interface or an enclosing type. I'm new to Eclipse and java. I suppose that I have some setting messed up? I'm running the most recent Eclipse on Linux:

```
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually realized that code completion was not working either. I checked the settings in 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced' and they seemed OK. I then re-ran with 'eclipse -clean'. After I did that, code completion and the new class wizard are working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to type some characters and then it will start looking for classes that start with those characters. Also, check that you don't have any filters set that you don't expect. You will see a tiny upside-down triangle on the upper right, click on that and go to the filters dialog.

Comment: I went to the filters dialog, and the Type Filters list is empty.

Comment: That's expected. Everything's fine then. Just type characters of what you want to search for.

Answer (score 0):

No. Every public and non final class could be your superclass. Proposing them all would force Eclipse to show thousands of classes, and would not really help you. You're supposed to know which class you want to extend. Just type its name, the beginning of its name, or the first letter of each of its words (ATM for AbstractTableModel, for example), and Eclipse will then show you matching classes.

Comment: That makes sense. However, I didn't see any matching classes, whatever I typed in. I did see "Initializing search indicies (0%)" occasionally, very briefly.

Comment: Try with some standard, extendable class like Thread or AbstractList. And remember Java is case-sensitive.